# How to integrate Zookeeper with Spark Driver program?

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to integrate Spark Standalone cluster with Zookeeper And I have a question on integration from Spark Driver program perspective.  I have 3 Spark Masters and I understand one of them will be elected and others run in a standby mode. According to the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#standby-masters-with-zookeeper) it says one can pass `spark://host1:port1,host2:port2` to spark context such that if one host goes down and other host becomes a leader and the driver would know who is the current leader. so my question really is instead of passing `host1_ip` and `host2_ip` can I simple ask Zookeeper to give me all the ip's of spark master? or simply pass zookeeper url.

Comment: As far as I know, Spark Standalone does not support multiple masters, only Mesos has this functionality

Comment: @T.Gawęda I am sure it does. Its in the documentation. But again my question really is what I need to do with Zookeeper from Spark driver program

Comment: Spark Standalone does support ZooKeeper. The documentation is pretty good actually, have you tried following it?

Comment: You are right, sorry! As @YuvalItzchakov said, documentation is quite good: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#standby-masters-with-zookeeper

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes and not only I read that documentation. I actually had integrated Zookeeper with spark master by myself and it works great. But I think I need to rephrase my question since I feel like I am probably unable to get my point across. I am editing it now to keep it really simple.